# Creating a Zip file with PHP?

Tags: php

this is my first time attempting to create a ZIP File in PHP.

What I am doing is, my PHP will search for files in a certain directory, grab them all and save them into a ZIP File. The zip file will then send the file to the browser to download. I am very close, but I am stuck at a certain part.

Here is my code:

```
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open('test.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    die ("Could not open archive"); }

    $myDirectory = opendir("../folder/plugins/".$id."");

    while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) { $dirArray[] = $entryName; }
    closedir($myDirectory);
    $indexCount = count($dirArray);
    sort($dirArray);
    for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
    if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){

    $file = "".$myDirectory."".$dirArray[$index].".zip";

    $zip->addFile($file, $file) or die ("cant add file");  ; 
    echo $dirArray[$index]; echo '</br>';

    }}

    $zip->close()or die("cant close");
```

I am getting the 'can't close' error when attempting to close. Please help me here, I can't find what I'm doing wrong in my code. This is what it is printing:

```
   filename1.png
   filename2.png
   can't close
```

:)

Comment: Have you looked at the error string returned by `getStatusString`?

Comment: In general, some code improvements: `$zip->addFile($file, $file) or die ("cant add file");  ;` (double semicolon), `$file = "".$myDirectory."".$dirArray[$index].".zip";` can be better written as `$file = "${myDirectory}${dirArray[$index]}.zip`, and in general for readability it's not a good idea to combine lines of code on one line as in `echo $dirArray[$index]; echo '</br>';`.

Answer (score 4):

Check the following line:

```
$zip->addFile($file, $file)
```

Is this what you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it working:

```
    <?php

        $dirArray = array();

        /* creates a compressed zip file */
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        if ($zip->open('dataminefiles.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
            die ("Could not open archive"); 
        }
        // open the current dir
        if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            // ignore hidden files          
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            // only zip specific files
                if ( substr($entry,-3,3) == "jpg" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "pdf" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "lsx" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "xls" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "doc" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "txt" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "png" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "gif" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "peg" ) {
                    // if allowed, add them to the array
                    $dirArray[] = $entry;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

        $indexCount = count($dirArray);
        sort($dirArray);
            // loop through the files and add them to the zip file
        for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
                $file = "{$dirArray[$index]}";
                $zip->addFile($file, $file);
        }
    // close the zip file
        $zip->close();

    ?>
```